# How to change View.backgroundColor using Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to change the background colour of a view controller using core data so the settings are saved for when the app is reopened. I have an entity called `Settings` with a attribute of `backgroundColor` of type `Bool`, if true the view will display a white background if false a black.

But as far as I am aware I am recreating multiple Settings instead of referring to one. **How can I change just one settings class without using arrays ?** Currently I am casting to an array, but it makes no sense and get the error when opening the view.

> Array index out of range

**Settings class**

```
class Settings: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var backgroundColor: NSNumber

}
```

**View Controller**

**UPDATED:**

```
var settingsArray: [Settings]!
var setting: Settings!
var backgroundSetting: Bool = true


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  backgroundSettings()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    backgroundSettings()
}

func backgroundSettings() {

    var error: NSError?
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Settings")
    self.settingsArray = moc?.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) as! [Settings]

    if settingsArray.count == 1 {
        setting = settingsArray[1]
    } else if settingsArray.count <= 0 {
      println("No settings in array")
    }

    if setting != nil {

        if setting.backgroundColor == 1 {
            backgroundSetting = true
        } else if setting.backgroundColor == 0{
            backgroundSetting = false
        }

    }


    if backgroundSetting == true {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    } else if backgroundSetting == false {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    }

}

@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {

    if setting != nil {

        if setting.backgroundColor == 1 {
            setting.backgroundColor = 0
        } else {
            setting.backgroundColor = 1
        }

        var error: NSError?
        moc?.save(&error)

    } else {

        println("No settings available")

        var settings = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Settings", inManagedObjectContext: moc!) as! Settings

        settings.backgroundColor = 1

        var error: NSError?
        moc?.save(&error)

    }

    backgroundSettings()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a check to see if an object already exists for a background color and if so edit that object instead of creating a new one, if not create & save a new one.

You could declare an optional property, say

```
var existingSetting: Setting?
```

Then in your initial fetch, try to assign it

```
self.settings = moc?.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) as! [Settings]

if let thisSetting = settings?[0] {

    existingSetting = thisSetting

}


if existingSetting != nil {

    // Set your color based on true / false
} else {
    // perform a default action
}
```

Then down in your Action

```
// Set your context

if existingSetting != nil {

    //Update this setting object

    existingSetting = true or false 
    // Save the context
} else {
    // Create a new setting
    // Save the context
}
```

Comment: A little confused with your example, I cannot use `thisSetting` in the action. But if you were referring to changing the value of the bool type  `backgroundLight` depending on `thisSetting` value I get the error using binary operands for type Bool and nil

Comment: updated, I meant to say existingSetting in the action - sorry!

Comment: and in the 2nd if in the fetch as well.

Comment: Getting an error, **Array index out of range** for `if let thisSetting = settings?[0]` in the function :/

Comment: Can you post your updated code? the optional in the array in the if let should prevent that.

Comment: Your updated code has a mismatch between self.settingsArray & if let thisSetting = settings?[0] - just a type o ?

Comment: Sorry about that, it was a typo.

Comment: Im going to accept your answer, Just having a problem when checking the array, the app crashes if the array is 0 :/ Have updated my code

Comment: Checking out your updated code - where do you define the context? Also remove the call to the fetch function in either viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear